# Haskell program to replicate elements in List (for k value it should be reapeted k times)

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. 
    e.g
   [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3]]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can construct a list that contains *`k`* times te item `x`, by writing:

```
replicate k x
```

So now we want to map every item `x` in the original list to a list that contains `x`, `x` times. We can for instance write it as:

```
replic the_list = map helper the_list
    where helper x = replicate x x
```

Or by using a *lambda expression*:

```
replic the_list = map (\x -> replicate x x) the_list
```

Or we can use the [**`join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) function:

```
import Control.Monad(join)

replic the_list = map (join replicate) the_list
```

We can also use an *eta-reducation* here: remove `the_list` both in the head and body of the function clause:

```
import Control.Monad(join)

replic :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
replic = map (join replicate)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
replicate' :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
replicate' l = map (\n -> take n (repeat n)) l
replicate' [1, 2, 3] -- [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3]]
```